# Laravel 5.5 form validation numeric/integer accepts non-digital characters like "+"

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I want to validate the form data if it is just numeric/integer (as in just numbers). Based on Laravel's documentation there are two specific validators for that. But the problem I'm facing is that both the validators accept non-numeric characters such as **"+"** or **"-"**.

> **numeric**
>
> The field under validation must have a numeric value.
>
> **integer**
>
> The field under validation must be numeric.

How can I make the validation to only accept numbers and not other non-numeric characters?

```
'main_telephone'    => 'numeric',
'main_fax'          => 'integer',
'direct_telephone'  => 'integer',
'mobile'            => 'integer',
```

**Below is the screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has come across this problem the best possible solution is to use regex. I do not know why I didn't think of this before.

```
'main_telephone'    => 'integer|regex:/^[0-9]*$/',
'main_fax'          => 'integer|regex:/^[0-9]*$/',
'direct_telephone'  => 'integer|regex:/^[0-9]*$/',
'mobile'            => 'integer|regex:/^[0-9]*$/',
```